# JUnit test case for methods returning void

Tags: java, junit

I have a method whose signature is:

```
void method1(int i,int j);
```

Now I wish to create a JUnit test case for this method, but I am not sure as to how I should make it.
I am a novice at Java, so please excuse me.

I know I need to use `assertEquals()` but I am not sure as to how I should use it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: A unit test verifies that the contract of the method is fulfilled. The contract should be written in the javadoc of the method. What does the method do? What is its contract?

Comment: Without more info or code it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Can't you show the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the method return void, is usually not a problem.
You need to think on how this method changes the state of your object and how you can retrieve this change in state.

Maybe you class has some getter method and you can call your assert on this one.
Sometimes it can even be the `toString()` of you class that you need to Assert.

If you post some code i can adapt my answer to be more concrete.

Comment: The problem is my class does not have a getter method...also I dont know the object that the coder is using..since i m in the testing team...i need to treat it as black box

Comment: If you don't know what the method is supposed to do, you can't unit test it. A unit test should be implemented by the author of the code, not by an external tester.

Answer (score 0):

A method that is `void` would indicate that something about the state of the object has changed.  You can tailor your unit test to verify what you expected to change did.

It would also be beneficial to include getters as necessary, to make retrieving state information about your object easier.